# String to decimal conversion

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want covert String to Decimal value e.g.

```
String str = "ABC"
```

I need result `65 66 67` How can get this result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would first need to choose a character set and encoding, unless your goal is to output Unicode codepoints in decimal. (Unicode codepoints are conventionally written in hexadecimal like U+0041 U+0042 U+0043.) Some answers mention ASCII, you could use that but it's only 128 characters whereas `String` is Unicode, which has about 110,000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, its more of a java question compared to android

```
String str = "ABC";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from character, use this:

```
char ch = 'A';    
int ans = (int) ch;
```

for String you can use:

```
String mString = "ABC";    
int ansA = (int) mString.charAt(0);
int ansB = (int) mString.charAt(1);
int ansC = (int) mString.charAt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop like following

```
String str = "ABC";
char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
for(int i=0; i< cArray.length(); i++){
    int ascii = (int) character;
    System.out.println(ascii );//Will print ASCII value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String abc = "abc";
        for(int i = 0 ;i<abc.length()-1;i++){
            abc.substring(i,i+1);
            char a = 'a';
            int ascii = (int) a;
            System.out.println(ascii+" ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below method stringToAscii()

```
public static long stringToAscii(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String ascString = null;
        long asciiLong;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
                    sb.append((int)s.charAt(i));
                    char c = s.charAt(i);
                }
                ascString = sb.toString();
                asciiLong = Long.parseLong(ascString);
                return asciiLong;
    }
```

Comment: I hope my answer helped you.